# Optimalize SQL query with left outer join and union

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, union

I have quite slow query and I want to make it faster - is it possible?

```
SELECT 
    k.Date,
    Levels,
    Used_id,
    Z_id,
    D_id,
    k.Client_id,
    f.Product_id
FROM 
    (SELECT Date, Levels, Used_id, Z_id, D_id, Client_id 
     FROM Client_Data
     GROUP BY Date, Levels, Used_id, Z_id, D_id, Client_id) k
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT Date, Client, Product 
     FROM Client_and_Product_Data 
     GROUP BY Date, Client_id, Product) f on f.Date = k.Date and f.Client = k.Client_id
union
SELECT 
    p.Date,
    Levels,
    Used_id,
    Z_id,
    D_id,
    f.Client_id,
    p.Product_id
FROM 
    (SELECT Date, Levels, Used_id, Z_id, D_id, Product_id 
     FROM Product_Data
     GROUP BY Date, Levels, Used_id, Z_id, D_id, Product_id) p
LEFT outer join 
    (SELECT Date, Client, Product 
     FROM Client_and_Product_Data 
     GROUP BY Date, Client, Product) f on f.Date = p.Date and f.Product = p.Product_id;
```

There are 9mln records in `Client_data` table, 300k records in `Product_data` table and 250k records in `Client_and_Product_Data` table.

The whole query takes 3-4 minutes.

What I'm doing in this query: In `Client_and_Product_Data` table I have connections between `Client` and `Product`. I want to have something like Cartesian product of `Client` and `Product` records, but I have to have also columns from `Client` and `Product` table.

Types of columns:
-`Date` - `smalldatetime`,
-`Levels` - `varchar`,
-`Used_id` - `int`,
-`Z_id`, `D_id`, `Client_id`, `Product_id` - `uniqueidentifier`.

Comment: you aren't using any `aggregate` functions in the `select` clauses. what is the purpose of  `group by` then?

Comment: what do have as  index?

Comment: @bisounours_tronconneuse - I don't understand your question (maybe because I don't use any indexes).
@vkp - I thought that when I reduce possible duplicates (they could be) in subqueries, I will have less rows to do `left outer join`.

Comment: @Monic 
Well your tables have indices and primary keys (certain collumns are indexed and retrieving with respect to these columns make things faster), whether you are aware of it or not. And to know how to make a fast query, you need to know which columns are indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query can probably take advantage of indexes.  I would recommend:

- `Client_Data(Date, Levels, Used_id, Z_id, D_id, Client_id)`
- `Client_and_Product_Data(Date, Client, Product)`
- `Product_Data(Date, Levels, Used_id, Z_id, D_id, Product_id)`

If you don't need to eliminate duplicates, then remove the `GROUP BY`s in the subqueries.  If there are no duplicates between the two queries, then change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll try. But I have such another question: what if I want to have string made out of 7 selected (like above) and concatenated columns - is it any faster method to do this too?

Comment: @Monic . . . I have no idea what you mean by "concatenated columns".    String concatenation in a `where` or `on` clause tends to prevent some optimizations, so it is more likely to slow the query down.  Perhaps you should ask another question.

Comment: Sorry for my English. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I'm using this query to get all 7 columns and then I'm doing string (or varchar) like this: col1+'|'+col2+'|'.... So I was wondering if it could be also fast when I use such concatenation (and of course in case of int or uniqueidentifier I would have to do `convert` function).     

But yes, maybe you are right, I should ask another question, because it's another problem.

Comment: Your clues (I used only indexes) allowed me to get all needed rows in 1,5 min, so it is really faster, thanks!